# Access my own domain url from my office System. Any unknown urls are blocked by my company

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, amazon-elb, appdomain, aws-application-load-balancer

I have purchased a domain from Godaddy and attached with A2Hosted VPS. My domain is accessible from  my personal laptop but not from my office laptop.

I am trying to access this website using any AWS provided solution, but don't want to host it in AWS.
As awsamazon.com urls are not blocked, so want to create a load balancer in aws and route it to my domain url.

Is AWS provide any solution for this?
I am ok to access my website using AWS load balancer.

Comment: As a test, is your website accessible from the office network if you enter the IP address instead of the domain name?

Comment: No its not accessible.

Comment: In that case, your company is block the IP Address (not the domain). Therefore, it will likely also block the IP address associated with a Load Balancer in AWS. Most 'blocking' on networks are via IP addresses rather than domains, because it can be very easily circumvented.